# Meteor Tabular not reacting to ReactiveDict's values changing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, datatables, aldeed-tabular

I'm using the great Tabular package. [https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-tabular](https://Tabular).

I'm making use of the client-side `selector` helper to Reactively change my table by having Server modify the query for my dataset.

I have multiple HTML `input`s that act as filters and am populating a ReactiveDict with the `values`. A search-button click event triggers the `ReactiveDict` to get populated with an Object using `.set`

Initialization of ReactiveDict

```
Template.tbl.onCreated(function () {
    const self = this;
    self.filters = new ReactiveDict({});
});
```

Population of ReactiveDict

```
'click #search-button'(e, template) {
            //clear to 'reset' fields in ReactiveDict that could've been cleared by User
            template.filters.clear();

            const searchableFields = getSearchableFields();

            //Initialize standard JS Obj that ReactiveDict will then be set to
            const filterObj = {};

            //Loop through search fields on DOM and populate into Obj if they have a val
            for (let field of searchableFields) {
                const value = $(`#${field}-filter`).val();

                if (value) {
                    filterObj[field] = new RegExp(escapeStringRegex(value.trim()), 'i'); 
                }
            }

            if (Object.keys(filterObj).length) {
                template.filters.set(filterObj);
            }
        },
```

Selector Helper

```
selector: () => {
            const filters = Template.instance().filters.all();
            const selector = { SOME_DEFAULT_OBJ,  ...filters };

            return selector;
        },
```

I'm noticing the server doesn't notice any changes from a ReactiveDict if all keys remain the same.
I'm testing this by logging in the serve-side's `changeSelector` md and verifying that my logging does not occur if just a value in selector has changed.

Is there a solution to this?

I.e. `{foo:'foo'} to {foo:'bar'}` should reactively trigger the server to re-query but it does not. But `{foo:'foo'} to {bar:'bar'}` would get triggered.

Is this an issue with how I'm using the ReactiveDict or is this on the Tabular side?

Thanks